# Google DFP Ad show for click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I want to show google dfp unit when user click on `navbar`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var navbar = false;
  var navslot = null;
  $(document).on('click', '.new_car_nav', function(){
    navslot = googletag.defineSlot('/10176910/NavBar', [[250, 250]], 'ad_navbar').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display('ad_navbar');
  });
});
```

Issue is that it gives an error

```
Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: $ is not defined
```

Either we can use jquery in it or not? If no then how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery, add this to your `<head>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `jQuery` library, you need to include it into the `head section` before any other library includes.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.